# Create a Foreign Key Using "Code First" but actually have the DB First

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have these views in my Sql Server database:

```
Shipment.Shipment
     * ShipmentId --> PK
     * CourierId

Ref.Courier
     * CourierId --> PK
```

Since these are views, there are no foreign keys on them.  The underlying tables are legacy and also do not have foreign keys.

But I want to have my entity framework model think that there are foreign keys.  (Specifically `Shipment.Shipment.CourierId => Ref.Courier.CourierId`)

I could do this in database first, but I recently switched to "code first" and I can't seem to get it to work using the `ForeignKey` attribute.

However, I don't really do "Code First".  I retrofitted my entity classes from the views in the existing database.

**So, using the "code first" syntax, how can I add an association/foreign key to my existing entities?** (even though there is not one in the database)

Here is a paired down version of my existing entities:

```
[Table("Shipment.Shipment")]
public partial class Shipment
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ShipmentId { get; set; }

    public int CourierId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Airbill { get; set; }
}


[Table("Ref.Courier")]
public partial class Courier
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CourierId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CourierName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: try adding public virtual Courier Courier { get; set; } in shipment class and public virtual Shipment Shipment { get; set; } in courier class

Comment: @AnshulNigam That did it!  So simple!  (Though I just needed to add to the shipment class for my scenario).    If you want to post as answer I will accept.  (Thanks!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to

```
[Table("Shipment.Shipment")]
public partial class Shipment
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ShipmentId { get; set; }

    public int CourierId { get; set; }

    /* this will tell EF about relationship with Courier,assuming it is 1-1 */
    public virtual Courier Courier { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Airbill { get; set; }
}


[Table("Ref.Courier")]
public partial class Courier
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CourierId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CourierName { get; set; }
}
```